# Accessing my other database from my website 1 to my website 2

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I have website 1 currently uploaded in the web and i have also develop a website 2 running on the localhost for now.. I want to access or get some value from the website 1 database to my website 2..is this possible using php query or javascripting? if not, what approach i need to take? thanks for the help

Comment: Are you trying to access a remote database on a webserver through PHP code running locally on your computer?

Comment: You should be able to access as many databases as you like, so long as you have the correct permissions and login credentials available.

Comment: is it possible to access a remote database on a webserver through PHP code running locally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, You have to just pass the parameters of the server details like this example.

```
<?php
//Connect To Database
$hostname='ukld.db.5510597.hostedresource.com';
$username='myusername';
$password='mypassword';
$dbname='testdb';
//your rest of code
?>
```

Comment: is this all i need to do? then i can make query then?

Comment: yes after this code connect with remote database and write your mysql queries. @jiulianjefCurato

Comment: Not entirely true, you need to setup the database so it allows remote connections

Comment: i got this error: Not connected : Host '49.145.123.191' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server,,What i need to set up?

Comment: you tried with @GeertJaminon comment for allowing remote connection for remote DB.

Comment: the same error..i didnt execute it in command line..sql command for wamp not working..do i need to copy the grant query or there need to be change?

Comment: can u show me the mysql_connect code after the decleration above?pls help

Answer (score 0):

To allow connections from an external IP-address, you will need to do the following as well:

> Grant access to a new database
>
> If you want to add a new database called foo for user bar and remote IP 202.54.10.20 then you >need to type the following commands at mysql> prompt:
>
> mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
>
> mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

[More information](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: i got this error: Not connected : Host '49.145.123.191' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server,is there still lacking?

Comment: my webhost do not grant remote connection,this is maybe the reason.,,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's simple.

`<?php`
`$hostname = "remote_host_name";`
`$database = "remote_database_name";`
`$username = "database_username";`
`$password = "database_password";`
`$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);`
`mysql_select_db($database, $con);`
`?>`

Use this `$con` as the second parameter while running query.
e.g. `mysql_query($query, $con);`

Make sure that you have granted the access of server 1 in server 2 mysql database.

Comment: can u give me a webhosting site that offers free and allow remote access to database servers

Comment: sorry but i did not know any free which support remote access to database.